# I need to connect multiple jradiobuttongroups and a jcombobox to a jbutton

Tags: java, eclipse

what i need to do is to connect two jradiobuttongroups and a combobox to a jbutton and when i click the jbutton the total of all the options appear in a textfield.

****(edit)by total i meant to say that you add up the chosen options(one for each category). You connect them to the calcular importe jbutton and in the ver dialogo jbutton you create a dialog window that shows you the microprosessor you selected and the final price ***

****(Important notice)i am working with eclipse and i cannot use <string with combobox so if someone can help me find a solution i would be thankfull****

```
package parciall;
import java.awt.Component;

public class Ventapc {

private JFrame frmVentaPc;
private final ButtonGroup PlacaMadre = new ButtonGroup();
private final ButtonGroup Memoria = new ButtonGroup();
private JTextField textField;
String micros[]={"Intel","Atlon","Turion"};
int tel=150;
int atlon=80;
int turion=120;
int asus=75;
int giga=320;
int msi=100;
int twomb=50;
int fourmb=80;
int eigthmb=130;
int monitor=250;
int discofijo=80;
int fp;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Ventapc window = new Ventapc();
                window.frmVentaPc.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Ventapc() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frmVentaPc = new JFrame();
    frmVentaPc.setTitle("Venta PC");
    frmVentaPc.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frmVentaPc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Tipo de Micro:");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(128, 15, 67, 22);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
    
    JPanel placamadrepanel = new JPanel();
    placamadrepanel .setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    placamadrepanel .setBounds(94, 52, 307, 42);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(placamadrepanel );
    
    JRadioButton asusbutton = new JRadioButton("Asus");
    PlacaMadre.add(asusbutton);
    placamadrepanel .add(asusbutton);
    
    JRadioButton gigabutton= new JRadioButton("GigaByte");
    placamadrepanel .add(gigabutton);
    PlacaMadre.add(gigabutton);
    
    JRadioButton msibutton= new JRadioButton("Msi");
    placamadrepanel .add(msibutton);
    PlacaMadre.add(msibutton);
    
    JPanel memoriapanel = new JPanel();
    memoriapanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    memoriapanel.setBounds(94, 111, 307, 42);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(memoriapanel);
    
    JRadioButton twomb = new JRadioButton("2MB");
    memoriapanel.add(twomb);
    Memoria.add(twomb);
    
    JRadioButton fourmb = new JRadioButton("4MB");
    memoriapanel.add(fourmb);
    Memoria.add(fourmb);
    
    JRadioButton eigthmb = new JRadioButton("8MB");
    memoriapanel.add(eigthmb);
    Memoria.add(eigthmb);
    
    JLabel lblPlacaMadre = new JLabel("Placa Madre:");
    lblPlacaMadre.setBounds(10, 80, 74, 14);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(lblPlacaMadre);
    
    JLabel lblMemoria = new JLabel("Memoria:");
    lblMemoria.setBounds(10, 131, 74, 22);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(lblMemoria);
    
    JCheckBox monitor = new JCheckBox("Monitor");
    monitor.setBounds(128, 160, 97, 23);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(monitor);
    
    JCheckBox discofjo = new JCheckBox("Disco Fijo 1TB");
    discofjo.setBounds(227, 160, 97, 23);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(discofjo);
    
    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textField.setText("0,00");
    textField.setBounds(237, 190, 87, 30);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
    
    JButton calcuimp = new JButton("Calcular Importe");
    calcuimp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            textField.setText ( "error");
        }
    });

    calcuimp.setBounds(94, 194, 115, 23);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(calcuimp);
    
    JButton verdial = new JButton("Ver Dialogo");
    verdial.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"el procesador es:"+micro,); 
        }
    });
    verdial.setBounds(94, 228, 115, 23);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(verdial);
    
    JButton salir = new JButton("Salir");
    salir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    salir.setBounds(235, 228, 115, 23);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(salir);
    
    JComboBox micro = new JComboBox();
    micro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    micro.setBounds(205, 15, 87, 22);
    frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(micro);
    
    micro.getSelectedItem();
}
}
```

Comment: What is the input dialog for?

Comment: When you click which JButton? What total are you talking about? The total cost of the options selected or just a list of the options selected? You need to remember, we didn't design this and we sure can't read your mind...at least not yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would want to do is exactly what you did with the JTextField...declare all pertinent Swing components as class member variables so that they can be accessed anywhere within the scope of the **Ventapc** class. Once this is done then you can create a method to verify that all required fields have a selection, maintain a sum from those selections, and insert the total price into the available JTextField (`textField`). Something like this:

```
private boolean verifyEntriesAndSetTotal() {
    boolean res = true;
    precioTotal = 0;
    
    // Processor
    if (micro.getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
        switch (micro.getSelectedItem().toString().toLowerCase()) {
            case "intel":
                precioTotal += intel;
                break;
            case "athlon":
                precioTotal += athlon;
                break;
            case "turion":
                precioTotal += turion;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Motherboard
    if (asusbutton.isSelected()) {
        precioTotal += asus;
    }
    else if (gigabutton.isSelected()) {
        precioTotal += giga;
    }
    else if (msibutton.isSelected()) {
        precioTotal += msi;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Memory
    if (twoGB.isSelected()) {
        precioTotal += twogb;
    }
    else if (fourGB.isSelected()) {
        precioTotal += fourgb;
    }
    else if (eightGB.isSelected()) {
        precioTotal += eightgb;
    }
    else if (sixteenGB.isSelected()) {
        precioTotal += sixteengb;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    
    //The OPTIONALS
    // Monitor Option
    if (chkMonitor.isSelected()) {
        precioTotal += monitor;
    }
    
    // Fixed Disk Option
    if (chkFixedDisk.isSelected()) {
        precioTotal += discofijo;
    }
    
    // Set the total price
    textField.setText(String.valueOf(precioTotal));
    return res;
}
```

in the `calcuimp` button's **ActionPerformed** event you would have something like this:

```
if (!verifyEntriesAndSetTotal()) {
    // Not all required items are selected.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmVentaPc, "Not all required selections have been made!", 
                                  "Invalid Selections", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

The above code is used in the runnable provided below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Ventapc {

    private JFrame frmVentaPc;
    private JComboBox<String> micro;
    private JRadioButton asusbutton;
    private JRadioButton gigabutton;
    private JRadioButton msibutton;
    private JRadioButton twoGB;
    private JRadioButton fourGB;
    private JRadioButton eightGB;
    private JRadioButton sixteenGB;
    private JCheckBox chkMonitor;
    private JCheckBox chkFixedDisk;
    private JTextField textField;
    private final ButtonGroup PlacaMadre = new ButtonGroup();
    private final ButtonGroup Memoria = new ButtonGroup();
    
    private final String micros[] = {"Intel", "Athlon", "Turion"};
    // Prices
    private final int intel = 150;
    private final int athlon = 80;
    private final int turion = 120;
    private final int asus = 75;
    private final int giga = 320;
    private final int msi = 100;
    private final int twogb = 50;
    private final int fourgb = 80;
    private final int eightgb = 130;
    private final int sixteengb = 200;
    private final int monitor = 250;
    private final int discofijo = 80;
    private int precioTotal = 0;    // Total Price
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Ventapc window = new Ventapc();
                    window.frmVentaPc.setVisible(true);
                    window.frmVentaPc.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Display in Center Screen.
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Ventapc() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frmVentaPc = new JFrame();
        frmVentaPc.setTitle("PC Sale");
        frmVentaPc.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 310);
        frmVentaPc.setResizable(false);
        frmVentaPc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("<html><font color=red><b>*</b></font> Micro Type:</html>");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(128, 15, 75, 22);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JPanel placamadrepanel = new JPanel();
        placamadrepanel .setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        placamadrepanel .setBounds(120, 52, 280, 42);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(placamadrepanel );
        
        asusbutton = new JRadioButton("Asus");
        PlacaMadre.add(asusbutton);
        placamadrepanel .add(asusbutton);
        
        gigabutton = new JRadioButton("GigaByte");
        placamadrepanel .add(gigabutton);
        PlacaMadre.add(gigabutton);
        
        msibutton = new JRadioButton("MSI");
        placamadrepanel .add(msibutton);
        PlacaMadre.add(msibutton);
        
        JPanel memoriapanel = new JPanel();
        memoriapanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        memoriapanel.setBounds(120, 111, 280, 42);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(memoriapanel);
        
        // NO ONE looks at a computer with Megabytes of memory ;)
        twoGB = new JRadioButton("2GB");
        memoriapanel.add(twoGB);
        Memoria.add(twoGB);
        
        fourGB = new JRadioButton("4GB");
        memoriapanel.add(fourGB);
        Memoria.add(fourGB);
        
        eightGB = new JRadioButton("8GB");
        memoriapanel.add(eightGB);
        Memoria.add(eightGB);
        
        sixteenGB = new JRadioButton("16GB");
        memoriapanel.add(sixteenGB);
        Memoria.add(sixteenGB);
        
        JLabel lblPlacaMadre = new JLabel("<html><font color=red><b>*</b></font> Motherboard:</html>");
        lblPlacaMadre.setBounds(10, 65, 90, 14);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(lblPlacaMadre);
        
        JLabel lblMemoria = new JLabel("<html><font color=red><b>*</b></font> Memory Size:</html>");
        lblMemoria.setBounds(10, 120, 90, 22);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(lblMemoria);
        
        chkMonitor = new JCheckBox("Monitor");
        chkMonitor.setBounds(128, 160, 97, 23);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(chkMonitor);
        
        chkFixedDisk = new JCheckBox("Fixed Disk: 1TB");
        chkFixedDisk.setBounds(231, 160, 120, 23);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(chkFixedDisk);
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField.setText("0,00");
        textField.setBounds(235, 190, 140, 30);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton calcuimp = new JButton("Calculate Amount");
        calcuimp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (!verifyEntriesAndSetTotal()) {
                    // Not all required items are selected.
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmVentaPc, "Not all required selections have been made!", 
                                                  "Invalid Selections", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
        calcuimp.setBounds(75, 194, 140, 23);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(calcuimp);

        JButton salir = new JButton("Leave");
        salir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                 System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        salir.setBounds(235, 234, 140, 23);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(salir);
        
        micro = new JComboBox<>(micros);
        micro.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        micro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                
            }
        });
        micro.setBounds(215, 15, 130, 22);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(micro);
        micro.getSelectedItem();
        
        JButton verdial = new JButton("See Dialog");
        verdial.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frmVentaPc, "<html><center>The processor is: &nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=blue><b>" 
                        + micro.getSelectedItem().toString() + "</b></font></center><br></html>", 
                                            "Processor Type", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); 
            }
        });
        verdial.setBounds(75, 234, 140, 23);
        frmVentaPc.getContentPane().add(verdial);
    }
    
    private boolean verifyEntriesAndSetTotal() {
        boolean res = true;
        precioTotal = 0;
        
        // Processor
        if (micro.getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
            switch (micro.getSelectedItem().toString().toLowerCase()) {
                case "intel":
                    precioTotal += intel;
                    break;
                case "athlon":
                    precioTotal += athlon;
                    break;
                case "turion":
                    precioTotal += turion;
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        
        // Motherboard
        if (asusbutton.isSelected()) {
            precioTotal += asus;
        }
        else if (gigabutton.isSelected()) {
            precioTotal += giga;
        }
        else if (msibutton.isSelected()) {
            precioTotal += msi;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        
        // Memory
        if (twoGB.isSelected()) {
            precioTotal += twogb;
        }
        else if (fourGB.isSelected()) {
            precioTotal += fourgb;
        }
        else if (eightGB.isSelected()) {
            precioTotal += eightgb;
        }
        else if (sixteenGB.isSelected()) {
            precioTotal += sixteengb;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        
        //The OPTIONALS
        // Monitor Option
        if (chkMonitor.isSelected()) {
            precioTotal += monitor;
        }
        
        // Fixed Disk Option
        if (chkFixedDisk.isSelected()) {
            precioTotal += discofijo;
        }
        
        // Set the total price
        textField.setText(String.valueOf(precioTotal));
        return res;
    }
}
```